# facet wrap distorts state maps in R

Tags: r, facet, facet-wrap

This question is an extension of a previous question I asked, see [Mapping different states in R using facet wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814768/mapping-different-states-in-r-using-facet-wrap). I want to display points in the maps, colored by their value. I can get this to work using the following code, which produces a decent looking plot, but I like the look of the 'sepStates' output that Mark Peterson provided better.

```
mn <- min(test$value); hist(test$value) 
mx <- max(test$value)
ggplot(map_data('state',region=states), aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
geom_polygon(colour='black',fill='white') + geom_point(data=test,aes
(x=Lon,   y=Lat, group=group, color=value),size=2.5, pch=16) +
facet_wrap(~region, scales = "free", ncol=3) + 
scale_colour_gradientn(limits = c(mn,mx),breaks=c
(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),colours=rev(rainbow(7)))
```

Let's say there's a temperature column added to the zip code data Mark provided.

```
datatest <- structure(list(zip =c 
("5246", "85118", "85340", "34958", "33022", 
"32716", "49815", "48069", "48551", "58076", "58213", "58524", 
"73185", "74073", "73148", "98668", "98271", "98290"), 
city = c("Chandler","Gold Canyon", "Litchfield
Park", "JensenBeach", "Hollywood", "Altamonte
Springs", "Channing", "Pleasant Ridge", "Flint", "Wahpeton", 
"Ardoch", "Braddock", "Oklahoma City", "Sperry", "Oklahoma City", 
"Vancouver", "Marysville", "Snohomish"), state = c
("AZ", "AZ","AZ", "FL", "FL", "FL", "MI", "MI", "MI", "ND", "ND", "ND",
"OK","OK", "OK", "WA", "WA", "WA"), latitude = c(33.276539, 33.34,33.50835, 
27.242402, 26.013368, 28.744752, 46.186913, 42.472235, 
42.978995, 46.271839, 48.204374, 46.596608, 35.551409, 36.306323, 
35.551409, 45.801586, 48.093129, 47.930902), longitude = c(-112.18717,    
-111.42, -112.40523, -80.224613, -80.144217, -81.22328, -88.04546, 
-83.14051, -83.713124, -96.608142, -97.30774, -100.09497, -97.407537, 
-96.02081, -97.407537, -122.520347, -122.21614, -122.03976),
temperature = c(45,87,33,66,12,69,45,78,23,39,41,104,50,53,40,88,56,29)), 
.Names = c("zip", "city", "state", "latitude", "longitude","temperature"), 
row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If I want to display this in facets by state with only 1 legend on the right, like the first code above produces, how do I do this? My current code looks like this:

```
sepStates <- lapply(states, function(thisState){
ggplot(map_data('state',region=thisState), aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
geom_polygon(colour='black',fill='white') + geom_point(data=datatest
[datatest$region == tolower(thisState),],aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group,
color=temperature),size=2.5, pch=16) + ggtitle(thisState) + coord_map() +
theme_void() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))})

plot_grid(plotlist = sepStates)
```

Using the 'cowplot' package still leads to the states being distorted using the following code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
legend <- get_legend(ok_plot)
prow <- plot_grid(ok_plot + theme(legend.position="none"),
az_plot + theme(legend.position="none"),
mi_plot + theme(legend.position="right"),
nd_plot + theme(legend.position="none"),
fl_plot + theme(legend.position="none"),
wa_plot + theme(legend.position="right"),
align = 'vh',
hjust = -1,
nrow = 2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to give the `test` dataframe in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks like it is on the right track, but you appear to have forgotten to include a few key components (e.g., the data and where you created the objects `ok_plot` etc.).

First, I find it easiest to create an object to hold whatever color scale you want to use. I am not sure where you are going with the `rainbow` palette, as the breaks don't seem to match the extent of your data. So, instead, I am going to use `viridis` to make one (the palette is great for sequential data).

```
library(viridis)
sharedScale <-
  scale_color_viridis(limits = range(datatest$temperature))
```

Then, create your separate plots as before. Note that there is a color mapping added, along with the `sharedScale`, and that I am suppressing the legends right away.

```
sepStates <-
  lapply(states, function(thisState){
    ggplot(map_data('state',region=thisState)
           , aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
      geom_polygon(colour='black',fill='white') +
      geom_point(aes(color = temperature)
                 , data = datatest[datatest$region == tolower(thisState), ]
                 , size = 4
                 , show.legend = FALSE) +
      sharedScale +
      ggtitle(thisState) +
      coord_map() +
      theme_void() +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  })
```

plotting this, as before, will give the maps you want (now with color). However, it won't have a legend. For that, we want to extract a single legend to share across all of the plots. Make *sure* that the values are the same in every plot (e.g., that you set the limits) when you do this.

```
sharedLegend <-
  get_legend(
    ggplot(datatest
           , aes(x=long,y=lat,color = temperature)) +
      geom_point() +
      sharedScale +
      theme_void()
  )
```

Now, we can stitch it all together using nested `plot_grid`. Inside, we generate the same layout as before (just the six states). Outside, we combine that with the legend. You will have to tinker with `rel_widths` to match the aspect ratio (and titling) that you want in your final product.

```
plot_grid(
  plot_grid(plotlist = sepStates)
  , sharedLegend
  , nrow = 1
  , rel_widths = c(6, 1)
)
```

Gives

[image]

Similarly, you may want to play with the legend title/size (or consider putting it under the map instead of next to it).

```
flatLegend <-
  get_legend(
    ggplot(datatest
           , aes(x=long,y=lat,color = temperature)) +
      geom_point() +
      sharedScale +
      labs(color = "Temp") +
      theme_void() +
      theme(
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold")
        , legend.text = element_text(size = 12)
        , legend.key.size = unit(24, "points")
        , legend.position = "bottom")
  )

plot_grid(
  plot_grid(plotlist = sepStates)
  , flatLegend
  , ncol = 1
  , rel_heights = c(6, 1)
)
```

Gives
[image]

Comment: @MarkPeterson, what was the purpose of nesting `plot_grid` calls?

Comment: @ConnerM. I wanted the legend centered relative to all plots and free to be a different height/width than the individual plots. The easiest way to do that is to generate the plot without legend (the `plot_grid(plotlist = sepStates)` portion) and add the legend to that composite plot (the parts wrapped around it).