# Mapping different states with geom_sf using facet wrap and scales free

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

First, I am aware of this answer : [Mapping different states in R using facet wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814768/mapping-different-states-in-r-using-facet-wrap)
But I work with object of library `sf`.
It seems that `facet_wrap(scales = "free")` is not available for objects plotted with `geom_sf` in ggplot2. I get this message:

> Erreur : Free scales are only supported with `coord_cartesian()` and
>   `coord_flip()`

Is there any option I have missed ?
Anyone has solve the problem without being forced to use `cowplot` (or any other gridarrange)?

Indeed, here is an example. I would like to show the different French regions separately in facets but with their own x/y limits.

### The result without scales = "free"

Scales are calculated with the extent of the entire map.

```
FRA <- raster::getData(name = "GADM", country = "FRA", level = 1)
FRA_sf <- st_as_sf(FRA)

g <- ggplot(FRA_sf) +
  geom_sf() +
  facet_wrap(~NAME_1)
```

[image: facet regions with geom_sf]

### The result using cowplot

I need to use a list of ggplots and can then combine them.
This is the targeted output. It is cleaner. But I also want a clean way to add a legend. (I know may have a common legend like in this other SO question :
[facet wrap distorts state maps in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852114/facet-wrap-distorts-state-maps-in-r))

```
g <- purrr::map(FRA_sf$NAME_1,
           function(x) {
             ggplot() +
               geom_sf(data = filter(FRA_sf, NAME_1 == x)) +
               guides(fill = FALSE) +
               ggtitle(x)
           })

g2 <- cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = g)
```

[image: facet regions with geom_sf and cowplot]

Comment: Does it distort even if you pre-project the polygons?

Comment: There is no distortion here. The "distort" word comes from the title of the other referenced question on SO. I rephrase the sentence to make it clear.

Comment: @SébastienRochette were you able to get a answer to this question. I am having this exact problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know you are looking for a solution using `ggplot2`, but I found the `tmap` package could be a choice depends on your need. The syntax of `tmap` is similar to `ggplot2`, it can also take `sf` object. Take your `FRA_sf` as an example, we can do something like this.

```
library(tmap)

tm_shape(FRA_sf) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_facets(by = "NAME_1")
```

[image]

Or we can use `geom_spatial` from the `ggspatial` package, but `geom_spatial` only takes `Spatial*` object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatial(FRA) + # FRA is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object
  facet_wrap(~NAME_1, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: I now have a reason to try `tmap` ! Let's add this on my list.

Comment: Although I admire the work in `tmap`, I am dependent on `geom_sf()` and this is not the answer to "Mapping different states with geom_sf", so should not be the accepted answer. It's a great answer in terms of outside the box thinking, but it does not answer the question of the OP. That the OP is satisfied with this answer makes it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @MSBerends Your interpretation of what is qualified as an accepted answer and how to upvote/downvote an answer seems to be different than most of the SO users, but I respect your opinion. Good luck on your future endeavor.