# R: Facet a map with ggplot2

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to facet a map with ggplot2 because is faster than tmap package. Lamentably the map that I got is not that I have in mind.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(ggspatial)


chile  <- getData("GADM",country="Chile",level=1)

chile2= chile[c(2,4:5,7,8,12:16),]
chile2$grupo=1
chile3= chile[c(1,3,6,9:11),]
chile3$grupo=2
mapa=rbind(chile2, chile3)

ggplot() +
  layer_spatial(mapa) +
  lims(x = c( -77.1,-65), y = c(-57, -15))+
  facet_wrap(~grupo)
```

[image: ggplot map]

Lamentably the map above is not what I need. With tmap I got the map below and is the map that really I need:

[image: tm map]

Do you know how solve this using ggplot2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done, though I'm not sure if it's really worth the effort.

There are two issues here:

1. Usually, you can get different scales (latitudes / longitudes in this case) in each facet of `facet_wrap` by setting `scales = "free"`, but `layer_spatial` only works with the `coord_sf` coordinate system, and `coord_sf` is hard-coded to only work with fixed scales (there's a [discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2651) on the ggplot GH page that covers how this came about);
2. Setting `lims()` explicitly defeats the purpose of free scales anyway.

For the first issue, we can go against the package developers' intention to define an alternative version of the coordinate system that accepts free scales. (I'm not saying that it *should* be done, but it *can* be. Caveat emptor.)

```
CoordSf2 <- ggproto("CoordSf2",
                    CoordSf,
                    is_free = function() TRUE)
trace(coord_sf, edit = TRUE)
```

Running the `trace(...)` line will result in a pop-up window with the code for `coord_sf`. Modify the last section from `ggproto(NULL, CoordSf, ...)` to `ggproto(NULL, CoordSf2, ...)` will point `coord_sf` to our modified `CoordSf2` instead of the original `CoordSf`. This effect will remain in place until the end of the current R session, or you can terminate it earlier by running `untrace(coord_sf)`.

For the second issue, I suppose the limits were set to show only polygons within the limits. We can perform this filtering step in the data frame, before passing it to `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr)

keep <- lapply(mapa@polygons, bbox) %>%                    # retrieve bounding box for each polygon
  lapply(function(x) c(x) <= c(-77.1, -57, -65, -15)) %>%  # compare each polygon's bbox against
  lapply(function(x) x == c(F, F, T, T)) %>%               # desired limits, if within, 
  sapply(all)                                              # results should be FFTT

keep # only the 10th polygon is outside the limits
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[11]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now plot with the subset of `mapa` polygons that fall within the desired limits, with facet scales set to "free" & `coord_sf` pointing to the modified version that allows it:

```
ggplot() +
  layer_spatial(mapa[keep, ]) +
  facet_wrap(~grupo, scales = "free")
```

[image: result]

Personally, though? I'd probably just make separate plots & stitch them together, like the `cowplot` method demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679646/8449629).

Comment: I agree with you,  the result dont compensate the effort, Thanks